# Change contents of memory with pointers?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory

I have tried to mess up memory with following code but changing values does not affect system operation.

```
byte obj = 0;
byte* pointer = &obj;
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    pointer[i] = 0;
    // or 
    // *(pointer++) = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

the program prints all `i` but stops working in last iteration. sometimes it throws access violation exception in middle of iteration.

- What are the values after pointer[0]. Real Contents of memory?
- Why setting all bytes to 0 does not affect system operation?
- What protects the memory from being changed?(Which throws Access violation).
- If its a process or thread (which violates the access) then it should be stored in memory itself. then how can it protect it self?

Im not trying to create virus or anything. I had this question about pointers and memory in my mind for long time. i just want to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the values after pointer[0]. Real Contents of memory?

Yes, it is. Well, as real as memory gets these days.

As you point to a local variable, it will be memory in the stack. You will write over the local variables and then the return address of the method, then the data on the stack for methods lower down. That's why it crashes when you try to leave the method.

> Why setting all bytes to 0 does not affect system operation?

Because each application lives in a completely separate virtual memory space. You can't write in operating system memory, because it doesn't exist in the virtual memory space of your application.

> What protects the memory from being changed?(Which throws Access
>   violation).

Your application has a limited area in the virtual memory space where it can access memory. When you try to access memory outside that area the system will either expand the virtual space or not allow it, depending on what memory you acess.

> If its a process or thread (which violates the access) then it should
>   be stored in memory itself. then how can it protect it self?

The process can't completely be protected from itself, as you have to be able to access some memory to work with. You can corrupt your own process, but you can't corrupt other processes as they are in their own virtual memory space.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system (together with the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)) prevents processes from accessing memory belonging to other processes. You would need something like [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) to mess up memory of other processes.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing zeros to the address of `obj` not memory address 0.

`obj` most likely somewhere in CLR heap.